# Spring Boot 3.0 Native: Code generation does not support org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigBuilder<?, ?>

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, spring-statemachine

Spring Boot 3.0 brings support for native image creation using GraalVM.

I've recently upgraded my project, which implements spring-statemachine-core 3.2.0, to Spring Boot 3.0 and was eager to try out the new native image creation. However, when I run `mvn spring-boot:process-aot`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to generate code for 'org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigBuilder@6b3b4f37' with type org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigBuilder<?, ?>
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.generateValue(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:186)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.lambda$addConstructorArgumentValues$3(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:151)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.addConstructorArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:150)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.DefaultBeanRegistrationCodeFragments.generateSetBeanDefinitionPropertiesCode(DefaultBeanRegistrationCodeFragments.java:146)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanRegistrationCodeGenerator.java:86)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.lambda$generateBeanDefinitionMethod$3(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethod.<init>(GeneratedMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod$2(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:85)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:83)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$applyTo$1(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethod.<init>(GeneratedMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.applyTo(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:66)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.applyTo(BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.lambda$processAheadOfTime$0(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.withCglibClassHandler(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:67)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.processAheadOfTime(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:53)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.performAotProcessing(ContextAotProcessor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Code generation does not support org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigBuilder<?, ?>
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.java:133)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.java:98)
        ... 31 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.052 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-12T20:41:00-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0:process-aot (default-cli) on project glamitoms: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

I've tried downgrading and switching versions of Spring SM but I get the same error every time. Are projects that implement Spring SM exempt from using Spring Boot native?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/1080